# cannot allocate an object of abstract type solution?

Tags: c++, oop

I have a homework in C++ to program a university.
I have two main abstract classes Student and Course.
In the Course, there are different child classes, such as SoftwareEngineering class... etc
In the Student, there are different child classes, such as SoftwareEngineering student class.. etc.

Now, in the Course child classes, each child class has a function to register a student

```
void register(Student &s);
```

When I call the function register of each course child class ( such as the software engineering course class), I want to push that student reference into a vector.
But I get the error

```
 cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Student'
```

the Student class IS abstract, and has child classes SoftwareEngineeringStudent and such.
But I -must- make the register function get an abstract object Student, not a specific type of student like SoftwareEngineeringStudent.

Is there a possible way around this?

here's a skeleton (not full code, of course!):

```
//Course.h
class Course{
virtual void reg(Student &s)=0

}
class SoftwareEngCourse : public Course{
void reg(Student &s);
}

//Student.h
class Student{
virtual void study(Course &c)=0;
}
class SoftwareEngStudent : public Student{
void study(Course &c);
}
```

now in the Course.cpp:

```
//Course.cpp
void SoftwareEngCourse::reg(Student &s){
   vector_of_Student_object.push_back(s);
}
```

Comment: How do you call register function? You want to pass point of the child class and not the Student class, that's probably the issue.

Comment: Show us the declaraton for `vector_of_Student_object`.  By the way, your variable naming is quite verbose.

Comment: I call the register function in the main. 
the vector is defined as protected in the father class Course as std::vector<Student> members;

By the way, perhaps the solution is dynamic casting?

Comment: @user1656647 dynamic casting? If adding to the vector was possible, it still wouldn't work because of slicing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the comments you said that your vector is declared as:

```
std::vector<Student> vector_of_Student_object;
```

...and therein lies the problem.  You trying to store `Student` objects in the `vector`, but you can't store a `Student` object because that class is abstract.  Consider the following psudocode:

```
void foo(Student s)
{
}

int main()
{
  SoftwareStudent ss;
  foo(ss);
}
```

What happens to `ss` when `foo` is called?  You are passing a `SoftwareStudent`, but `foo` just takes a `Student`.  So `ss` is implicitly converted to its base class, `Student` which, since `foo` takes a `Student` by value, tries to construct a new `Student` by calling:

```
Student::Student(const Student& rhs)
```

In other words, the `SoftwareStudent`-specific attributes of `ss`
You may not have implemented this constructor yourself, in which case the compiler did it for you.

The end result is you are trying to instantiate an abstract class because `foo` takes a `Student` by-value.  This obviously won't work since you can't instantiate an abstract class.

This relates to your actual problem because your `vector` is a `vector` of `Student` objects, stored again by value.  When you insert an object in to a vector, that object is copied. You end up trying to instantiate `Student` objects, which you can't do because `Student` is abstract.

You need to store something other than `Student`, either a `Student` reference or pointer.  Since you can't have a `vector` of references, that leaves you with pointers.

Whenever dealing with pointers, it's best to deal with smart pointers rather than raw pointers as with smart pointers you don't need to worry as much about releasing the object, and very often you don't even have to use `new` explicitly.  `std::shared_ptr` is probably the easiest to incorporate here, although `std::unique_ptr` might be a better fit semantically.

Comment: This is pure amazing explanation, thank you.
Will try it in a bit. Also, for some reason it is not identifying std::shared_ptr, even though I tried including tr1/memory, memory, and boost.
But I will see about it.
Will leave a comment in a bit when I try it.

Comment: Tried it and it worked.
the register function of the course receives a reference to student.
I declared the vector as a vector of pointers to student objects, and did vector.push_back(&s) (the address of the reference that came into the register function).
This worked.
But this leaves me wondering, this would be a whole lot of memory clearing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, make `vector_of_Student_object` a vector of (smart) pointers to students instead.

A vector of objects is probably not what you want anyway, since the objects will be [sliced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: I dont know what smart pointers are and how to use them. Will look it up, but will be happy if I can get further indepth explanation on how to use smart pointers.

Comment: @user1656647 it's a C++ idiom which provides pointer-semantics to objects whose memory is managed automatically and provide clear ownership. You should look it up, in-depth description isn't going to fit in a comment box.

Comment: Upon further exploration, I've noted that we are allowed to use shared_ptr! will surely look it up. would shared_ptr in boost help?

Comment: @user1656647 yes, a vector of `boost::shared_ptr` or even `std::shared_ptr` would fix the issue. But then you'd also have to change the function to accept one of those instead of a student by reference.

Comment: Thats the problem. I am not allowed to change the structure of the register function

Comment: @user1656647 then I don't see a way of doing it safely. You could take the address of the object and pass it in the array of pointers, but then if the object goes out of scope, you'd have a dangling pointer in the vector.

Comment: I have looked into the answer given by John Dibling. It worked perfectly. I simply transformed the vector to take a POINTER to a student object!
Thanks for the magnificent effort!

Comment: @user1656647 that's exactly what I said in my answer + note that it isn't safe due to the reasons pointed out in my previous comment.

Comment: I am very sorry as I did not understand it this way, excuse my manners.
In this homework I am very limited to the exact skeleton of the functions so I can not modify the register at all. I guess I'll just have to do correct memory management.

Comment: @user1656647 I didn't mean you should accept my answer instead of John's. If it was clearer, then it's worth the tick. What I was saying is that you should be aware of the drawbacks that come with the approach.

Comment: Thanks to you I am aware of them now.
Thank you so much :)

Comment: Luchian's answer is exactly the same as mine, the only difference being I prattled on and on about it.  Since Luchian was first by quite a while, it's probably his answer that should be accepted.